# Styling tab ant design

Tags: css, reactjs, tabs

I am using Ant design tabs and an i want to change the header using just css to look like the following.

[Tab header with outward curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpWVO.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1):

```js
var menuItems = $('.main-navigation li');

menuItems.on("click", function(event) {
    
  menuItems.removeClass("active");
  
  $(this).addClass("active");
  
  $(".main-content").css({
    "background": $(this).data("bg-color")
  });
  
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
  min-width: 925px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
  /*  &::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 16px;
      left: 0;
      width: 798px;
      height: 12px;
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
      z-index: 5;
    }*/
}
.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-navigation li {
  float: left;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 -1rem;
  position: relative;
}
.main-navigation li.active {
  z-index: 6;
}
.main-navigation a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.main-navigation svg {
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.main-navigation span {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem 0 0 3.3rem;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.main-navigation .tab-1 {
  z-index: 4;
}
.main-navigation .tab-1 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-1-bg);
}
.main-navigation .tab-2 {
  z-index: 3;
}
.main-navigation .tab-2 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-2-bg);
}
.main-navigation .tab-3 {
  z-index: 2;
}
.main-navigation .tab-3 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-3-bg);
}
.main-navigation .tab-4 {
  z-index: 1;
}
.main-navigation .tab-4 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-4-bg);
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #76a0c0;
  margin: -1.6rem 0 0 0;
  padding: 3rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

.article {
  background: white;
  padding: 5rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.article h2 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #76a0c0;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- TAB TEMPLATE -->
<svg height="0" width="0" style="position: absolute; margin-left: -100%;">
  
  <defs>
    
    <filter id='shadow'>
      <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic">
        <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0"/>
        <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0"/>
        <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
       <feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.2"/></feComponentTransfer>
      <feOffset dx="5" dy="1" result="shadow"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
        
    <linearGradient id="tab-1-bg" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="65%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgba(136, 195, 229, 1.0);" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgba(118, 160, 192, 1.0);" />
    </linearGradient>
    
    <linearGradient id="tab-2-bg" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="65%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgba(149, 190, 233, 1.0);" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgba(112, 153, 213, 1.0);" />
    </linearGradient>
    
    <linearGradient id="tab-3-bg" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="65%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgba(61, 149, 218, 1.0);" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgba(43, 130, 197, 1.0);" />
    </linearGradient>
    
    <linearGradient id="tab-4-bg" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="65%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgba(72, 204, 243, 1.0);" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgba(71, 194, 243, 1.0);" />
    </linearGradient>
      
  </defs>
  
  <path id="tab-shape" class="tab-shape" d="M116.486,29.036c-23.582-8-14.821-29-42.018-29h-62.4C5.441,0.036,0,5.376,0,12.003v28.033h122v-11H116.486
   z">
  
</svg>

<nav role="navigation" class="main-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab-1 active" data-bg-color="rgba(118, 160, 192, 1.0)">
      <a href="#home">
        <span>Home</span>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
           <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-2" data-bg-color="rgba(112, 153, 213, 1.0)">
      <a href="#about">
        <span>About</span>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
          <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-3" data-bg-color="rgba(43, 130, 197, 1.0)">
      <a href="#clients">
        <span>Clients</span>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
          <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-4" data-bg-color="rgba(71, 194, 243, 1.0)">
      <a href="#contact">
        <span>Contact</span>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
          <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="main-content">
  <article class="article">
    <h2>An Article Right Here, Boss.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa totam cumque ad repellendus ab ea repellat aperiam accusantium labore officia est culpa fugiat eaque magnam a. Labore molestias ea at maiores inventore veritatis cupiditate cum doloribus quisquam eum et asperiores!</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: this wasn't antd.